# How do I know the presence of nvprof inside CUDA program?

Tags: cuda, nvprof

I have a small CUDA program that I want to profile with `nvprof`. The problem is that I want to write the program in such a way that

- When I run `nvprof my_prog`, it will invoke `cudaProfilerStart` and `cudaProfilerStop`.
- When I run `my_prog`, it will not invoke any of the above APIs, and therefore can get rid of profiling overhead.

The problem hence becomes how to make my code aware of the presence of `nvprof` when it runs, without additional command line argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you measured and verified that cudaProfilerStart/Stop calls introduce measurable overheads when nvprof is not attached? I highly doubt that this is the case.

If this is a problem, you can use `#ifdef` directives to exclude these calls from your release builds.

There is no way of detecting whether nvprof is running, since that kind of defeats the purpose of profiling - if the profiled application "senses" the profiler and changes its behavior.